# Can I limit transactions to the cash available in my Square Cash account?

Tags: credit-card, money-transfer

I need to set up a "credit card" that has a limited balance that I can reload, for use online. I understand that I can crate a limited balance card for online use with several services (such as [GiftCards](http://www.giftcards.com)), but I would prefer to use something with an easier to use app and the ability to reload. [Square Cash](https://cash.me) seems to fit the bill (sorry) but I can't tell whether I can limit withdrawals from my account to the balance in my Square Cash account.

Can I limit transactions to the cash available in my Square Cash account, or will charges automatically pull from an associated bank or credit card if I exceed my Square Cash balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the balance in Square Cash isn't sufficient for a transation, the transaction will simply fail.

And the only way any cash can end up in the Square Cash balance is if you explicitly transferred it. Nothing will be automatically transferred (e.g., from an attached bank account or source) to cover a transaction.